# Change value to a global variable and take it value in other class

Tags: c#

I have a global variable in class "X", public int fileCounter = 0;

in a method of this clas I increase the value to n... "fileCounter ++;"

I need to take this value in other class, the problem is at this moment returns the value in 0

how can I do this?

Comment: What dou you mean by 'global variable'? And please post some more code.

Comment: Please post a code snippet so we can see what you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean you have a member variable `fileCounter`. Could you post a code extract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a public field (or perhaps property) in a class and wish to use that value in another class.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FileCounter;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        FileCounter++;
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.SomeMethod();

        Debug.WriteLine( string.Format("FileCounter: {0}", foo.FileCounter ) );
    }
}
```

Remember that fields are instance-based unless you declare them as static.

Comment: I have a problem, in my case the method SomeMethod() of the class Foo received some parameter, like this SomeMethod(string filePath, int logSelected),so, how can do this?

Comment: @ale - I do not see why that would make any difference. Conceptually, what I have shown should work. That Foo.SomeMethod is named different or takes different parameters shouldn't matter unless Bar.SomeMethod is unable call Foo.SomeMethod.